# Why image compression doesnt use overlapped data?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, signal-processing

For example in audio codecs like Opus, MDCT is used with 50% percent overlap to avoid ringing artifacts. Why a similar approach is not used in image codecs. e.g., JPEG uses non-overlapping 8x8 blocks ?

Answer (score 0):

Later lossy image codecs like [JPEG2000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_2000) *do* use overlapped transforms, but these techniques just weren't around when JPEG was being defined.  The wavelet transform that JPEG2000 is based on hadn't been invented yet, and time-domain anti-aliasing techniques like MDCT were extremely new.

For the MDCT in particular, as far as I know it is not used for image compression at all, even Today.  I would guess that's because its basis vectors are asymmetric, which makes it intuitively difficult to choose for imaging applications.